# Menu tree structure in json format

Tags: php, laravel

I need to create menu in below json format.
Below is my table from which I'm fetching data:-

```
id  name        parent
1   Company     0
2   About Us    0
3   Contact Us  0
4   Networks    0
5   Services    0
6   News        0
7   company1    1
8   Compnay 11  7
```

and and my excepted format is given below.

```
{
    "0":{
            '1':'Company'
                        {
                        '7':'company1'
                            {
                                '8':'Compnay 11'
                            }
                        }
        },
        {
            "2":'About Us'
        }

}
```

i have tried the below code

```
function categoryList($parent,$level)
{
    Global $catArr;
    $categories = Category::where('parent','=',$parent)->get();
    foreach($categories as $allCat) {

        $catArr[$allCat->id] = str_repeat("-", $level).$allCat->name;
        $level++;
        categoryList($allCat->id,$level);
        $level--;
    }
    return $catArr;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your given JSON format doesn't seem a valid one. Just recheck & share once again. You can use https://jsoneditoronline.org/ for validating your JSON string.

Comment: ignore my json format...i need menu tree like structure in json format.Tree structure means child menu should belongs to its parent menu

Comment: "_Global $catArr;_"?? And please explain why `'1'` should have single quotes while `"2"` should have double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Laravel package to achieve this, Here is the plugin you can use `https://github.com/etrepat/baum`.

For this you need to change your database table structure and also need to make some changes in your model.
And this package provide you full hierarchy of data as parent-child.